# How to solve an error in Xcode 10: Multiple commands produce....../Fonts

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, compiler-errors

I have React Native App. And I installed react-native-vector-icons library. And after I get this error in Xcode:

Multiple commands produce '/Users/jocoders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/openCalls-gtlsipogexxyteffomqvumgwiihd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/openCalls.app/Fonts':

1. Target 'openCalls' (project 'openCalls') has copy command from '/Users/jocoders/openCalls/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts' to '/Users/jocoders/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/openCalls-gtlsipogexxyteffomqvumgwiihd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/openCalls.app/Fonts'
2. Target 'openCalls' (project 'openCalls') has copy command from '/Users/jocoders/openCalls/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/Fonts' to '/Users/evgeniykireev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/openCalls-gtlsipogexxyteffomqvumgwiihd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/openCalls.app/Fonts'

Comment: Find out if the set library code has no duplicate.

Answer (score 12):

I just had the same issue specifically with `react-native-vector-icons` using RN 0.61.4 and Xcode 11.2.1 while upgrading an app to > 0.6. What I ended up doing to get it to build was go to *Build Phases -> [CP] Copy Pod Resources -> Deleted references to react-native-vector-icons fonts*. Then rebuilt and everyone ran nicely. I did notice the fonts were already in the `Resources` folder on the project explorer on the left. I also commented out the `# pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'` line in the Podfile and ran `pod install` but not sure if the affected it or not. This is just a patch but hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: This kind of works, but the problem reappears when I run `pod install` again, found a permanent solution here https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/1074

Answer (score 2):

Remove duplicate items from Copy bundle resources.

[image: For ref please check image]

Answer (score 0):

I checked all links from **XCode** errror and have not found any dublicate files.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the vector icons to the Font group from XCode, adding them directly to the *'./ios/{app name}/Info.plist'* file like shown below worked for me,

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key> 
<array>
    <!--Other fonts.-->
    <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
    <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
    <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
    <string>Feather.ttf</string>
    <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
    <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
    <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
    <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
    <string>Fontisto.ttf</string>
    <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
    <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
    <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
    <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
    <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
    <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
    <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
</array>
```